# IE9 & IE7 'Storage' is undefined

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9, storage, local-storage

In IE9 & IE7, I'm getting `'Storage' is undefined` on line 2 of the following:

```
if (localStorage) {
    Storage.prototype.setJsonItem = function(key, jsonItem) {
        // code I have that sets a JSON object, irrelevant to this question
    }
}
```

1. Why is IE7 even getting to line 2, since localStorage should be null because localStorage is not supported in IE7.
2. Why is Storage undefined in IE9?

Thanks!  It would be sweet if IE just died altogether :P  #jk #sorta

**EDIT:**

Changing it to if `(localStorage && typeof Storage != 'undefined')` seemed to do the trick.  Any more elegant way of doing it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using [lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/), but any of the following [storage libraries](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Storage-libraries) would work.